# Background image is not showing Ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

recently I switched from Ionic v3 to v4.
In v3 was easier to add a background image,but in v4 is not working.

```css
:host {
  .background-image {
    background: url('../assets/imgs/carp.jpg') no-repeat 100% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-content class="background-image" no-scroll padding>

</ion-content>
```

and is giving an error for the image url

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After asking the question to the Ionic forum I find the solution for this.The problem was that the path was not correct.Ionic 4 has different method for adding the background image.Here is the solution:

```css
:host {
  .background-image {
    --background: url('../../assets/gifs/nature.gif') 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with --background ?

Answer (score 0):

The assets directory path is wrong. Try

```
:host {
  .background-image {
    background: url('assets/imgs/carp.jpg') no-repeat 100% 100%;
  }
}
```